# generating first status on rails 3.2.16

Tags: ruby, windows, ruby-on-rails-3

When generating my first status, that is when I do the localhost/statuses I have the following error:

```
ExecJS::RuntimeError in Statuses#index

Showing C:/Users/NEBELYN/ruby1/gopbook/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #6 raised:

(in C:/Users/NEBELYN/ruby1/gopbook/app/assets/javascripts/statuses.js.coffee) 
Extracted source (around line #6):

3: 
4: Gopbook 
5: <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %> 
6: <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %> 
7: <%= csrf_meta_tags %> 
8: 
9: Rails.root: C:/Users/NEBELYN/ruby1/gopbook
```

HERE IS MY GEM FILE

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.16'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
```

Comment: You seem to be on windows. Show your Gemfile

Comment: i updated the post with my gem file

Comment: What do you mean by "generating my first status"?  Please show all commands you ran and any inputs you gave to your web app.

Comment: mkdir fbook, cd fbook, rails new fbook, rails server, ctlr c, rails generate scaffold status name:string content:text, rake db:migrate, rails server, the server works at localhost:http:127.0.0.1:3000, but when i do http://127.0.0.1:3000/statuses, it gives me the erro error above.thanks